# When does the PR Bonus affect Focus Power Tests?

Tags: deathwatch

In the Deathwatch Core Rule book, the paragraph describing Focus Power Test states:

> A Focus Power test is a Willpower Test that determines
>   whether a functions successful. The amount of time it takes
>   to make this test is determined by the power being used and
>   may be a Free Action, Half Action, Full Action or Reaction.
>   In most cases, passing a Focus Power Test simply means that
>   the power has manifested, while failing the test means that it
>   has not. However, degrees of success or failure may also play
>   a part depending on the type and nature of the power being
>   used. Many powers also indicate an Opposed Willpower Test,
>   especially when used against an unwilling foe. In these cases,
>   the Opposed Test is also the Focus Power Test, and even
>   if the psyker scores better than his opponent but does not
>   roll under his Willpower, the power will still fail. **You may
>   add a bonus to your Focus Power Test equal to 5 times the
>   Psy Rating used for the power.** A Focus Power roll of 91-00
>   always fails.

Does this apply to all Focus Power Tests, or just to opposed tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your quote (which was not changed in the errata), 5xPR bonus applies to each and every Focus Power test.

For example, rank 1 Librarian with WP 54 and Psi Rating 3, who *pushes* to PR 6, has to roll under 54 (WP) + 0 (Focus Power test is Challenging by default)  +5*6 (PR) = 84.

Comment: So, my rank 1 Librarian with a 54 WP (2 advancements) and 3 PR, who constantly pushes his power (increasing to PR 6) succeeds on any roll under 84?

Comment: Exactly. Updated the answer with your example. Do remember, though, that pushing ascertains psychic phenomena and, therefore, you will roll on Perils table once per 4 invocations, since 1st rank Librarian does not have any perils-related talents. Consequences may be grave.

Comment: Yeah, I know. In 1 short game, I knocked myself out and summonded a vortex of doom (2 separate events). Also, I took the Rite of Sanctioning to minimize the effect of psychic phenomena.

Comment: I've added the entire paragraph on Focus Power Tests. If I were the one running the game, I would say (based on the context) that it only applies during opposed checks.

Comment: That could be an interesting house rule, though rules as written state pretty clearly that you apply the bonus to every Focus Power Test, opposed or not.